# trying to get iframe content height always fails

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to get the content height of one of the iframes in a webpage using javascript.

but **obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight** always gives 150px (or the height of the iframe element itself if I set it to a default value).

Both the parent HTML page and the iframe content are local on my PC and share the same folder.

Any suggestions?

the relevant parts of my code:

```
...

<iframe id="I2" name="Content" src="home.html" style="width: 860px; margin-left: 330px; top: 0px; border: none; overflow:hidden" 
     scrolling="no" 
     onload="onloadingContent(this)">
</iframe>

...

<script>
function onloadingContent(obj) 
{
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
} 

...
```

Comment: yes, post your code and css

Comment: edited the question - added the code